No sound after Jammy install, tried refresh/install, PulseAudio and PipeWire. Sound settings show: no volumen, no output devices detected
After having resolved "Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS localhost tty1 does not recognize my user name" and regaining the graphic interface, I have been trying to resolve the no sound issue. Prior to the Jammy installation my audio (with PulseAudio) functioned. I have tried following:https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/ with no success. Are ALSA or Jack factors in this? My Settings/Sound doesn't detect output device, so there is no test sound either. I am suspicious that this has something to do with ALSA because the machine takes a long time to boot. I do not know if or how to proceed with https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/sound/
...I have no knowledge of how packages work.
